# Missed! symbol cards against Slab the Killer

Tags: bang

Can I play a Bible, Shibata or some other Missed! symbol cards against Slab the Killer?

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange! This looks like a pretty good question, but more details would be helpful. What are the reasons you think that this might be up for debate? Something about the wording on the cards? Also, adding the card text would be helpful so potential answerers don't have to dig out the game to check the card text.

Answer (score 2):

You can play any card with the Missed! symbol against Slab the Killer, however you will need a total of 2 of them in order to miss. What the means is if you only have one card that you can play and it lets you draw card after you use it, you can play the card, draw your card and if it provide you with a second Missed! symbol you can then play it and miss the shot. If you do not get another card that lets you miss you will still take the hit even though you played one miss card.